# Code printing all contents of txt file instead of specific line

Tags: python, python-3.x

I have the code written below and the goal of the program is to let the user list all cars in a list and then ask for specific details on just one specific car via input. However, when the user inputs the car they want details on, it also prints all of the cars in the txt file instead of just that one car.

The code from the main file where the program is written:

```
while True:
command = input("(L)ist all cars, get a cars (D)etails, or (Q)uit: ").strip().lower()

if command == "q":
    break
if command == "l":
    for car in cars:
        car.displayCar()
elif command == "d":
    carName = input("Enter car name: ").strip().lower()
    for car in cars:
        if car.is_match(carName):
            car.display()
else:
    print("Invalid command")
```

The code from the file where the above is using to call the users input:

```
    def is_match(self, carName):
    if self.carName == True:
        return False

    if carName == self.carName:
        return False

    return True
```

Comment: `if self.carName == True`??? What's that for?

Comment: I think your problem is swapping `True` and `False` in `is_match`.

Answer (score -1):

```
def is_match(self, carName):
    if self.carName == True:
        return False

    if carName == self.carName:
        return True

    return False
```

You got your true and false mixed up in your is_match function. I bet if you really examine, you'll find that it's printing out every line except the line for the queried car.

Comment: Unfortunately this just seems to make nothing print at all

Comment: @Tommy Gonna need more information then. How are you ingesting the car database? Is it possible you didn't convert the name to all lower case or that you need to trim spaces or something?

Answer (score -1):

From what I understood, You need to print the car details if the given string is matching car name in the car class.

```
def is_match(self, carName):
    if(self.carName):
        return self.carName.lower()==carName
```

It would be great if you can upload full code with sample input and output